# Remove shipping in order summary

Tags: magento2, orders, shipping-methods, order-summary

I want to remove or hide the shipping in `order summary` like in the picture below, because it will always free shipping. How can i remove it? 
[image]

Comment: If you are using custom theme, one option is to hide it in your custom theme. just hide it using css.

Comment: No i dont use custom theme.

Comment: then according to magento docs you should create a a new theme inheriting from Magento Blank or Luma. This is the simplest way available. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html
Editing the core magento theme is not a good idea, since you changes will be overwritten by update

Answer (score 0):

Please check the path and use below code. This may help you.

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml
<referenceBlock name="shipping-information" display="false" />
```

Comment: The shipping method is still there, it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

This price and Shipping carrier name is coming from JS file and not the PHTML file. you can find JS file at below location

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js

Answer (score 0):

Disable shipping UI component thru XML layout file

override the XML file in your custom theme and disable the shipping component.

app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!--Remove fields-->
                                                            <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout file named `checkout_index_index.xml` under your module/theme's `view/frontend/layout/` directory, and use this code to remove the shipping component from the Checkout page:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

As you mentioned, your website is always going to offer free shipping, so you might want to remove the shipping section from Cart page as well. If a customer reaches Shipping step, selects a Shipping method and then eventually goes back to Cart page, another Shipping line will show up in Cart Summary section.
[image]

To remove this Shipping at Cart page, create another layout file named `checkout_cart_index.xml` also under your module/theme's `view/frontend/layout/` directory, and use this code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="block-rates" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="price" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then finally clear the cache using command `php bin/magento cache:clean` and refresh to page to see the result.

Let me know if my answer helps or there is any mistake.

Happy coding!